# Replace DynamoDB Scan operation with Query

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk, dynamodb-queries

I am using DynamoDB Scan operations to get all items from DynamoDB table. The code is as below:

```
"use strict";
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");

module.exports.get = async () => {
  try {
    const dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

    console.log("getting items");

    const params = {
      TableName: "ProductsTable",
    };

    const result = await dynamodb.scan(params).promise();

    console.log("got results", result.Items);

    return { body: JSON.stringify(result.Items) };
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    return {
      status: 500,
      message: error.message,
      body: JSON.stringify(error),
    };
  }
};
```

But scan is not an efficient operation an is not recommended. How can I use Query operation to get all items from the table ? Can I replace scan Operation with Query to get all items ? Is there any other way to get all items from the table ? Please let me know.

thanks

Comment: It's worth noting that your code will not return all items once there are more than 1MB worth of data in the DB. You need to add a paging mechanism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scan is only inefficient because it has to look at everything.

If you want to return everything anyways, there's no reason not to use Scan.

In fact, you could use the built in [parallel scan](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Scan.html#Scan.ParallelScan) to speed up the process.

Query() has to be run in parallel manually by your application code.

Comment: Such a good point.  The advice to avoid scans is likely the right advice in most situations.  However, as you've pointed out, if you have to fetch all items it's the right tool for the job.